# R: Special requirements for a clustering algorithm

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I'm working on a clustering problem in R, but my needs are pretty different from anything I've been able to find in the literature or language thus far. 
   My data's not complex: it's basically a three column dataframe that contains latitude, longitude, and a value for time.  Here's the first few rows:

```
myDF <- data.frame(latitude=c(34.11119,34.11148,34.11119,34.11119,34.11148)
                  ,longitude=c(-84.34192,-84.34192,-84.34234,-84.34192,-84.34234)
                  ,date_value=c(0.07820023,.08092014,.04058449,.08755208,.04478588))
```

My basic need is to find observation making up small clusters of points that are close together in space and time, and look at those separately from the vast majority of the data.

Here's the two differences between what I want and what I've been able to find:

1. I don't care about 99% of the data.  Rather, I would like to just get a small subspace of the overall data that are the tightest clusters.  I originally envisioned an algorithm that did partial clustering that greedily just merged datapoints into clusters until some number of iterations had been done, or some number of subclusters had been reached, but I don't know of a package that would specifically do that (Cross-clustering is an algorithm that supposedly does cross-clustering, but I didn't have much luck getting the code to run).  Another approach I've been looking at is to run a hierarchical clustering algorithm like HClust and just get the lowest branches from the tree, but I'm having trouble recovering the data I want, namely, the observations (or some identifier for them) that comprise the clusters, and a size/density type measure that would let me separate a "tight" cluster from a "loose" cluster.
2. The cluster type output I've gotten from the existing packages are great for showing me a cluster on a plot, but I'd like to merge that to my original dataframe so I could separate out observations that go together into a tight cluster, versus the rest of the data.

Can anybody help out here?  I'm solid in R programming and data science, but I'm not very familiar with clustering techniques thus far.

Comment: Your question is not about code, I think it's going to fit well [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). However how do you define "...a small subspace of the overall data that are the tightest clusters"?

Answer (score 1):

Of course, we cannot do any clustering on the five data points 
that you provided, so I will illustrate using some artificial 
data.  I am simply going to use x and y coordinates, analogous
to your lat-lon, and skip the time component,  but the same 
thing will work in your three dimensional case. My artificial 
data has 50 background noise points and two clusters, one with 
20 points, the other with 30 points.  The 30 point cluster is 
a little looser than the 20 point cluster.

We can get the grouping that you want using various clustering 
algorithms. You mentioned `hclust` so I will use that and I will 
also show how to use `dbscan`.  Both require some tuning.

**Artificial data**

```
set.seed(123)
x = c(runif(50, -10,10), rnorm(20, 1, 0.5), rnorm(30, -3,1))
y = c(runif(50, -10,10), rnorm(20, 1, 0.5), rnorm(30, -3,1))
df = data.frame(x,y)
plot(df, pch=20)
```

[image: Original Data]

**hclust**

Processing with `hclust`. I chose to use the "single link" 
method of determining distances. Also, I (somewhat arbitrarily) 
asked it to split into 47 clusters. Most of these should be 
one point clusters that we will eliminate as the noise. We 
hope to get two significant clusters.  You will need to 
experiment with your data to find a good number of clusters to use.

```
HCS = hclust(dist(df), method='single')
HC47 = cutree(HCS, 47)
table(HC47)

HC47
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 
 2  1 28  2  1  1 22  1  1  1  1  2  2  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 
28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 
 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  1  1  1
```

We see that clusters 3 and 7 are large and all others are small. 
We can relabel the clusters so that all of the small clusters are 
grouped together (as the noise).

```
Tight1 =rep(1,100)
Tight1[HC47 == 7]  = 2
Tight1[HC47 == 3] = 3
plot(df, pch=20, col=Tight1)
```

[image: hclust clustering]

Of course, you can store Tight 1 as a label for which points are in
the two clusters and the noise.

**DBSCAN**

DBSCAN is a great clustering method. You don't need to choose 
the number of cluster and it specifically models some of the 
points as noise. You do need to choose a parameter `eps` that 
essentially determines a local density that will be used to decide 
if points are part of a cluster or part of the noise.

```
library(dbscan)
DBS = dbscan(dist(df), eps=0.9)
table(DBS$cluster)
 0  1  2 
49 29 22
```

The points in "Clust 0" are the noise points. So we see that 
DBSCAN found two large clusters and 49 noise points.

```
Tight2 = DBS$cluster+1
plot(df, pch=20, col=Tight2)
```

[image: DBScan clustering]

You could store `Tight2` as the groupings (2 clusters or noise).